# I've heard that it's never a good idea to go with payment protection plans offered by credit card companies. Is this true?

Tags: credit-card, loans

I'd like to think my bank isn't trying to swindle me when they call and try to sell me one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about who are they protecting:  only themselves.  Just like mortgage insurance, you pay the premium so in case you can't pay your bill, they still get to cash in the policy.

Upside, you don't owe them money when you can't pay.
Downside, you more or less paid them.

If you get hurt, can't work and can't pay your bills the best option for you is to call your creditors and try to arrange something specific to the situation.  But only when it happens.  If things go completely wrong, or there is a debt attributed to you that isn't really yours, you have the option to not pay them.  So my opinion is why pay for insurance for them, let the bank pay their own premiums.

Comment: +1.  Agree.  I'd also add that it's far more important to have a long-term disability (LTD) policy in place to cover the "get hurt, can't work" case. LTD is important to have, and the self-employed often overlook it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd always scoffed at them too, and I don't have any CC insurance myself. However my friend was made redundant a few months back and his credit card protection scheme is paying a fair percentage of his (fairly large) balance each month, far more than the insurance cost him.

This is the **only** positive story I've heard about any credit card insurance but it made me think.

I guess it depends on the fine print of the particular agreement, but if you're not sure your job is safe and you have a large balance, it *may* be worth considering.

Comment: Interesting. Is it paying anything *more* than the minimum payment?

Comment: They're paying a fixed percentage (I think it is 10%) of the balance off per month, which considering the size of his balance is far more than the minimum payment